# What will happen when you light up all the torches in "On the Rain-Slick Precipice of Darkness 3"?

Tags: penny-arcade-3

When you enter the Altair on the third floor, the Altair maiden suggests that these torches will light up after you reach every pin to it's maximum amount.

After finishing the game I noticed that except one torch every other one lights up so I've had some fights in Colosseum and all of my pins reached

> level 40.

When I go to the Altair now, the maiden says:

> a portal appeared but it seems to be incomplete

What should I do next? Is there anything there to be found?

Comment: someone please add proper tags! I couldn't add a tag to match game name!

Comment: the full game title is too long for a standard tag, so I abbreviated.

Comment: @pixel the game never mentions what max level is, and it allows you to go beyond that that's why I marked that as an spoiler.

Comment: @gajet readded spoiler tag, apologies

Answer (score 3):

In October of 2012, the [Lair of the Seamstress DLC](http://store.steampowered.com/news/9197/) was released which enabled a dungeon in the Atelier of the Dowager Praxesse once

> all of the class pins reach level 40

Once you pass hurdle you can explore the dungeon which culminates with

> a battle with the Seamstress, creator of the class pins, herself.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't lead anywhere... *[yet](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=31482757&postcount=2)*.

More will probably be added in a later update.